# Running out of memory because of get Query

Tags: php, laravel

Currently, I am using a get Query to get all my user information and display it through an API call. But the problem I am running in to is that my database has gotten so big that my server runs out of memory.

I tried searching online for the best practice solution to this problem, but can't find a concrete answer. Some people are suggesting I place a `->chunk(300);` behind the `->get()` but other people are saying this is incorrect.

I really would like to find out the best way to fix the problem I am having.
Below you can find an example of the code I am currently using to get all the user information (this code is running out of memory).

```
$users = Users::select([
            'users.id as id',
            'users.type as type',;
            'users.created_at AS created_at',
            'users.firstName AS firstname',
            'users.lastName AS lastname',
            'users.email AS email',
        ])
            ->get();
```

I hope somebody can help me out to fix this problem.

Comment: Even if you'd solve the memory problem, this would probably mean the response would be ginormous…?! The usual way is to *paginate* responses, i.e. to return a fixed number of records, and the next set can be requested with `?page=2` etc.

Comment: _Not a solution_ But I have no idea why you have all those alias's which are the same as the actual column names. But it makes me think you should show us a lot more of the real code as there may well be other oddities that could be causing your problems

Comment: The response needs to be pretty big because the data is being loaded into Excel. That is why I don't want to add paginate because it would require multiple request the get the whole dataset.

Comment: So why not write the data row by row into a .csv or even a .xlsx (using [phpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)) Then there is no reason to create a huge array, which is probably your problem. Then send the spreadsheet file to the user.

Comment: Can you explain what are you going to do with that huge amout of data after quering from the DB ?

Comment: I am just trying to export it for analysis purposes. I understand that writing it to a .csv or a .xlsx file is better but currently my system is not set up for this. What I am looking for right now is a simple way to make this old method work. Is there really know way to split this query up in a way that doesn't overload my memory?

Comment: How about a for-loop where you use `LIMIT` AND `OFFSET` to retrieve only a few (thousand?) records at a time? I am not sure how that would fit in with the way you load it into Excel though. Could you provide some details on how you would get `$users` loaded into Excel?

Comment: Also, is it really your server that is running out of memory or are you hitting a maximum as configured in your `php.ini`?

Comment: I increased the server's PHP memory_limit and that will fix this problem temporarily. Seeing as the aplication is being replaced by the end of the year this should be enough for now. Thanks everybody for your help. It does surprise me there is no simple way to split the ->get() into multiple as to not overload the memory.